# How to pass an optional RenderFragment from a parent component to a child component in Blazor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

**Context:**
We have an Blazor application with the following 3 files:

- ChildComponent.razor
- ParentComponent.razor
- Test.razor (this is the consumer, which uses the parent component)

**ChildComponent.razor**

```
<div>
    @if(Body != null)
    {
        @Body
    }

    @if(Footer != null)
    {
        <div class="footer">
            @Footer
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }
}
```

**ParentComponent.razor**

The ParentComponent uses the ChildComponent. We want to pass the `ParentFooter` to the Childcomponent´s `Footer`:

```
<ChildComponent Footer="ParentFooter">
    <Body>
        <p>@Text</p>
    </Body>
</ChildComponent>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ParentFooter { get; set; }
}
```

The consuming file is **Test.razor** and looks like this:

```
<ParentComponent Text="Hello World"></ParentComponent>
```

We do not use a `<ParentFooter></ParentFooter>` here, because the footer is optional.

**Problem:**

We get an exception in the browser´s console:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Delegate to an instance
> method cannot have null 'this' (Parameter 'this')

**Possible Solution:**

In the file **ParentComponent.razor**, we pass the Footer by an reference and make an `null`-check:

```
<ChildComponent Footer="ParentFooter" @ref="m_ChildComponentRef">
    <Body>
        <p>@Text</p>
    </Body>
</ChildComponent>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ParentFooter { get; set; }
    
    private ChildComponent m_ChildComponentRef { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();

        if (ParentFooter != null)
        {
            m_ChildComponentRef.Footer = ParentFooter;
        }
    }   
}
```

But this is is a bad way, because we get an warning:

> BL0005:Component parameter should not be set outside of its component.

**Question:** How can we pass an optional RenderFragment to an child component?

Comment: Have you solved the problem or you would still want to know this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your parameter to a default value in child component
so it would look something like this

```
<div>
@if(Body != null)
{
    @Body
}

@if(Footer != null)
{
    @Footer
}
```

```
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Body { get; set; } = null;
    
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; } = null;
}
```

in Parent component you also set default value

```
 @if(ParentFooter != null)
  {
   <ChildComponent Footer="ParentFooter">
        <Body>
            <p>@Text</p>
        </Body>
    </ChildComponent>
    }
else {
// show something else 
}
    @code
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ParentFooter { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

if this doesn't help could you post github link

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Using `CascadingValue` works:

**ParentComponent.razor:**

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <ChildComponent>
        <Body>
            <p>@Text</p>
        </Body>
    </ChildComponent>
</CascadingValue>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ParentFooter { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildComponent.razor:**

```
<div>
    @if (Body != null)
    {
        @Body
    }

    @if (ParentComponent != null && ParentComponent.ParentFooter != null)
    {
        <div class="footer">
            @ParentComponent.ParentFooter
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ParentComponent ParentComponent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }
}
```

**Test.razor:**

```
<ParentComponent Text="Hello World">
    @* <ParentFooter>Footer</ParentFooter> // <- Optional *@
</ParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you'd like to construct your footer with `RenderFragment`, it's gonna be easy to pass on.

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
<ChildComponent Footer="@GenerateFooter()" />

@code {
    // Your Method that will generate footer for you
      private RenderFragment GenerateFooter() {
           return builder => {
                   builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(YourFooterComponent));
                   builder.AddAttribute(1, "YourRandomAttribute", "YourValueForAttribute")
                   builder.CloseComponent();
               }
      }
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@*The place where you'd like to show your footer.*@
@Footer


@code{

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }

}
```

If you don't want to create another component just for footer, you can do this by builder.OpenElement()... and create elements you require along-with requisite styles and classes, all can be done using attributes. BlazoreUniversity is a website with a lot of cool stuff.

Let me know if it helps you, better for future too. Because this is already very late since the question is posted.